# nullpointer exception in aggregate operation in kafka stream

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

below is code snippet,

```java
streamsConfiguration.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, "wordcount-live-test"); 
streamsConfiguration.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "brokerIP:port"); 
streamsConfiguration.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass().getName()); 
streamsConfiguration.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass().getName()); 
streamsConfiguration.put(StreamsConfig.TOPOLOGY_OPTIMIZATION, StreamsConfig.OPTIMIZE);

StreamBuilder builder = new StreamBuilder(); 

KStream streamData = builder.stream(inputTopicName);

streamData.groupByKey(Grouped.with(jsonSerde,jsonSerde)) 
    .aggregate( //some transformation );

KafkaStreams kafkaStreams = new KafkaStreams(
    builder.build(streamConfiguration), 
    streamConfiguration
);
```

here we are not using session window and this snippet gives me perfect result. But when I introduce session window with this stream then it gives `null` pointer exception for aggregate function.

can anybody help here

Comment: What version are you using? It would be helpful if you can provide a full stacktrace as well.

Comment: I am using version 2.1.0. i am trying to calculate min and max on one attribute. but it is working without session window. with session window getting erro

Comment: @SwapnilDixit, could you add stacktrace?